# How to validate enum in DTO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, enums

In the domain model object I have the following field:

```
private TermStatus termStatus;
```

TermStatus is an enum:

```
public enum TermStatus {
    NONE,
    SUCCESS,
    FAIL
}
```

In the DTO, I have the same field as in the domain object. The question is, how can I validate the passed value? If the API client now passes an incorrect string with the enum value as a parameter (for example, `nOnE`), it will not receive any information about the error, only the status `400 Bad Request`. Is it possible to validate it like this, for example, in the case of `javax.validation` annotations like `@NotBlank`, `@Size`, where in case of an error it will at least be clear what it is. There was an idea to make a separate mapping for this, for example `"items/1/complete-term"` instead of direct enum transmission, so that in this case the server itself would set the `SUCCESS` value to the `termStatus` field. But as far as I know, these things don't look very good in REST API, so I need your ideas

Answer (score 6):

Instead of validating enum directly, you could check whether String is valid for specific enum. To achieve such an effect you could create your own enum validation annotation.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumValidatorConstraint.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@NotNull
public @interface EnumValidator {

Class<? extends Enum<?>> enum();
String message() default "must be any of enum {enum}";
Class<?>[] groups() default {};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then you need to implement validator to check whether String exist as a part of this enum.

```
public class EnumValidatorConstraint implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, String> {

Set<String> values;

@Override
public void initialize(EnumValidator constraintAnnotation) {
    values = Stream.of(constraintAnnotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
            .map(Enum::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return values.contains(value);
}
}
```

Lastly, you need to annotate your field with @EnumValidator.

```
@EnumValidator(enum = TermStatus.class)
private String termStatus;
```

In case of not matching String a MethodArgumentNotValidException will be thrown. Same as for @NotNull or other constraint validation.

Comment: Can we write this way in spring  

@EnumValidator
private TermStatus termStatus;

Comment: You have to add suitable library to your pom.xml/build.gradle file. In case of spring-boot it would be spring-boot-starter-validation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to implement your own response after validation and tell the API client that the data in your received DTO is invalid and return message with the actual received value (nOnE in your case) and maybe the list of your valid values (if that's not gonna be a security concern). Also, I think the ideal http status for your response would be 422 instead of a generic 400 Bad Request.

For your actual validation implementation, I think you can just directly compare the converted value from DTO to ENUM of the data you received from the API client against your ENUM values in the back-end. If equals to any of the ENUM values, then it's a valid request (200) else, 422.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a utility method inside your `enum` like below
    private String text;

```
TermStatus(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
public static TermStatus fromText(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(bl -> bl.text.equalsIgnoreCase(text))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

And set value in `dto` like below

```
dto.setTermStatus(TermStatus.fromText(passedValue))
if(dto.getTermStatus()== null)
throw new Exception("Your message");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use String data type for `termStatus`. Because of client sends String value for this. Then you have to create Custom validation constraints to fix this as below.

**ValueOfEnum**

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValueOfEnumValidator.class)
public @interface ValueOfEnum
{
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**ValueOfEnumValidator**

```
public class ValueOfEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValueOfEnum, CharSequence>
{
    private List<String> acceptedValues;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValueOfEnum annotation)
    {
        acceptedValues = Stream.of(annotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
            .map(Enum::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CharSequence value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return acceptedValues.contains(value.toString());
    }
}
```

Now you can `@ValueOfEnum` annotation for your domain model. Then add `@Validated` annotation in front of your controller class domain object.

```
@ValueOfEnum(enumClass = TermStatus.class, message = "Invalid Term Status")
private String termStatus;
```